# Why can't TypeScript infer presence of required property in a union term when another prop is asserted to actually collapse the union to one term?

Tags: typescript, types, type-assertion

The scenario is that given a function that accepts a single parameter, an object that has type the union between two overlapping types, where one of the union sides has some additional required properties:

```
// assume types A, B, C are arbitrary defined types
function myFunc(inputParams: {commonProp: A | B} | {commonProp: C, extraProp: string}) {
  // see below
}
```

Now in the function body we assert the `commonProp` property to be of a single type, and accordingly we should be able to infer whether the `extraProp` will be present. For example, if `inputParams.commonProp` is of type B, then we would expect `inputParams.extraProp` to be undefined.

```
function isC(o: any): o is C {
  // somehow check and return whether o is of type C
}

function myFunc(inputParams: {commonProp: A | B} | {commonProp: C, extraProp: string}) {
  if (isC(inputParams.commonProp)) {
    const myVar = inputParams.extraProp; // does not work, but I would expect it to
  }
}
```

However, this fails with:

> Property 'extraProp' does not exist on type '{ commonProp: A | B; } | { commonProp: C; extraProp: string; }'.
>     Property 'extraProp' does not exist on type '{ commonProp: A | B; }'

Why is this the case, why isn't TypeScript able to tell from the assertion that since commonProp is of the type such that the supplied `inputParams` can only be of type of one term of the union, it can collapse this union into a single concrete type where the `extraProp` property is required. Why does it still consider that the `inputParams` can be either of the union term types.

```js
type A = {
  t: "a"
}

type B = {
  t: "b"
}

type C = {
  t: "c"
}

function isC(o: A | B | C): o is C {
  return o.t === "c";
}

function myFunc(inputParams: {commonProp: A | B} | {commonProp: C, extraProp: string}) {
  if (isC(inputParams.commonProp)) {
    const myVar = inputParams.extraProp;
  }
}
```

See this [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKVgC4oCICGOKAviiqJFAEILJobY4BGhJZ40AwjaulrgMYtSAMwCuAO37AAlgHtxUaQGcOAClnY4AHypQdHAJTZZipVC48oAJwjBRVhbIB0wBPEQ5BAbmIiJUuQUAWxAAMX9VaXEwUWAABTwrPCClbCR%20WSCg%20TirWTBNPSoiIvTM7PFc-OwOABooCAAPYCSqgqglFqiAcyIDWnRpYShIlUjo2ISklKcMrJy8sAN%20y3QM8U6oEIA1RJoomPjE5KUnJpa8Np90EiIgA) for a working demo.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```js
type A = {
  t: "a"
}

type B = {
  t: "b"
}

type C = {
  t: "c"
}

type RegularCase = { commonProp: A | B }
type EdgeCase = { commonProp: C, extraProp: string }
type Input = RegularCase | EdgeCase

function isC(input: Input): input is EdgeCase {
  return input.commonProp.t === "c";
}

function myFunc(inputParams: Input) {
  if (isC(inputParams)) {
    const myVar = inputParams.extraProp // ok
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WKOlMW)

**UPDATED**
My previous comment was wrong. The problem with `isC` typeguard, is that you are checking `commonProp` instead of `inputParams`.
See this:

```js
type AB = { commonProp: A | B }

type WithExtra = { commonProp: C, extraProp: string }

function myFunc(inputParams: AB | WithExtra) {

  if (isC(inputParams.commonProp)) {
    inputParams.commonProp
    const myVar = inputParams.extraProp;
  }
}
```

You pass `inputParams.commonProp` and typeguard, accordingly, only checks `commonProp` and it is infered as a `c`. However, you are not checking `inputParams` itself. Because `extraProp` is a property/part of `inputParams` and not of `commonProp`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: "I mean, they work, but then you need to create a reference to dotted property"

Comment: @zr0gravity7 made an update